# Creating a linearly spaced array of a particular size

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector

I am new to MATLAB and currently working on my homework assignment. I am trying to declare the `x` variable as the following:

> Create a linearly spaced array `x` of size (1 × 200) comprising values ranging from `–pi` to `pi`.

I've tried this code:

```
x=[-pi:200:pi];
```

but I'm not sure if it's the correct way to do this or not.

Comment: [`linspace`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linspace.html) function will do it, but learning to use the colon syntax is also a very good idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `linspace` as follow:

```
x = linspace(-pi, pi, 200);
```

check this out for an example:
https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linspace.html

Answer (score 1):

The other answer shows how to use `linspace`, this is the correct method.

But you can also use the colon operator and some simple arithmetic to do this:

1. `x = -pi : 2*pi/199 : pi` -- This means: go from -π to π in steps of such a size that we get exactly 200 values.
2. `x = (0:199) * (2*pi/199) - pi` -- This means: create an array with 200 integer values, then scale them to the right range.

Note that you shouldn't use square brackets `[]` here. They are for concatenating arrays. The colon operator creates a single array, there is nothing to concatenate it with.